# Delete only lateral edge in MS-excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, cells

Is it possible to delete only the lateral edges in a excel matrix?

In the attacched image you can see tha matrix and you can notice that is almost impossible to delete left/right formatted edges without deleting up/down ones.

[formatted edge matrix excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Huw8O.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the cells that contain that *edge*, then go to Cell Formatting, then go to Limits.

There, you will be presented a rough draft on how the cells' borders are done. In your case, just click once on the middle border to disable it.